# Sentence scoring from word score

Tags: python, nlp

I have a large forum about dog with tagged posts. Index scores from document frequency * text frequency gives me a perfect measure of what a topic should be about. For example

```py
print (getscores('dog food'))
# keyword scores range between 1 and 2
# {'dog':2,'food':1.8,'bowl':1.7,'consumption':1.5, ..... 'like':1.00001}
```

From there it seems easy to score sentences and find the sentence that best represents the topic, or so I thought. In this example the second sentence has a great fit.

```py
def method1 (sen):
    score = 1
    for word in sen.split():
        score=score*scores.get(word,1)
    return score

def method2 (sen):
    score = 1
    for word in sen.split():
        score=score*scores.get(word,1)
    return score / len(sen.split())

scores = {'dog':2,'food':1.8,'bowl':1.7,'consumption':1.5,'intended':1.4}
sens = ['dog food','dog food is food intended for consumption by dogs','like this one time at band camp there was all this food and and a dog this dog who ate all the food and then my bowl was empty']


for sen in sens:
    print (sen)
    print (method1(sen))
    print (method2(sen))

#dog food
#3.6
#1.8 (winner method 2)
#dog food is food intended for consumption by dogs
#13.607999999999999
#1.5119999999999998
#like this one time at band camp there was all this food and and a dog this dog who ate all the food and then my bowl was empty
#22.032220320000004 (winner method 1)
#0.7868650114285716
```

Averaging scores will favor short sentences while adding scores will favor long sentences. Compensating for sentence length (each word is multiplied by .92 or so) will work for one topic but will need another factor for the next topic.

So that approach will get me nowhere. Is there any known method of scoring sentences that will give me the sentence with the highest keyword weights but also takes into account keyword density and sentence length?

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Multi-word expressions](https://aclweb.org/aclwiki/Multiword_Expressions) (MWEs) in your processing pipeline, your results might improve. This pre-processing would typically be done before the TfIdf step. The code below illustrates how they are used:

```
from nltk.tokenize import MWETokenizer

#Instantiate the tokenizer with a list of NWEs:
tokenizer = MWETokenizer( [('dog', 'food'), ('band', 'camp')])

tl1  = tokenizer.tokenize('dog food is food intended for consumption by dogs'.split())
print(tl1)
tl2 = tokenizer.tokenize('like this one time at band camp there was all this food and and a dog this dog who ate all the food and then my bowl was empty'.split())
print(tl2)

#['dog_food', 'is', 'food', 'intended', 'for', 'consumption', 'by', 'dogs']
#['like', 'this', 'one', 'time', 'at', 'band_camp', 'there', 'was', 'all', 'this', 'food', 'and', 'and', 'a', 'dog', 'this', 'dog', 'who', 'ate', 'all', 'the', 'food', 'and', 'then', 'my', 'bowl', 'was', 'empty']
```

The [Spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features) dependency parser and POS tagger can be useful for extracting such MWEs.

The example below will detect some compound nouns which are likely to be MWEs:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

sens = ['dog food','dog food is food intended for consumption by dogs','like this one time at band camp there was all this food and and a dog this dog who ate all the food and then my bowl was empty']

def getCompoundNouns(sentence):
    doc = nlp(sentence)
    answer = []
    for t in doc:
        if t.dep_ == 'compound' and t.pos_  == 'NOUN':
            neighboringToken = t.nbor()
            if neighboringToken.pos_  == 'NOUN':
                answer.append((t.text, t.nbor()))
    if not answer:
        return(None)
    return(answer)

for s in sens:
    print(getCompoundNouns(s))

#[('dog', food)]
#[('dog', food)]
#[('band', camp)]
```